# Difference between all, all of, each

Tags: determiners

What is the difference in the following three sentences regarding usage of the determiner?

> The right to work implies the obligation on the part of the government to give a job to **all the unemployed**.

> The right to work implies the obligation on the part of the government to give a job to **each of the unemployed**.

> The right to work implies the obligation on the part of the government to give a job to **all of the unemployed**.

Answer (score 2):

`each of` is less ambiguous as it implies each person gets one job each. `all` or `all of` (I can't think of a real difference beside `all of` sounding more natural) could mean one common job given to everyone. Of course in this example it is obvious common sense to assume `each`, but in some cases it does have double meaning:

> The company is giving a $1000 bonus to all of its employees

could either imply a collective sum for a team, or one for each individual as this less ambiguous sentence implies:

> The company is giving a $1000 bonus to each of its employees

Comment: I don't think  "...each of the unemployed," would be used in this context.  It would be more commonly phrased, "...every unemployed person."  If I had a good explanation for when to use 'each' and when to use 'every' I would be quick to share it.  But I do not.

Comment: Yes, `each of the unemployed` doesn't sound right. If the question was not finding the difference, but selecting one correct choice, then everyone would definitely go for `all of the unemployed` even though it's technically ambiguous